# rails 3 limiting access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

i already made admin controller with session, and now i try to limiting access to some page
this is my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :authorize, :except => :login
protect_from_forgery

protected
def authorize
unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  flash[:notice] = "Please log in"
  redirect_to :controller => 'admin', :action => 'login'
end
end
end
```

and this is controller i tried to limit its access

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

def index
@photos = Photo.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @photos }
end
end

def show
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @photo }
end
end

def new
@photo = Photo.new
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @photo }
end
end

def edit
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
end

def create
upload = params[:upload]
@photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
respond_to do |format|
  if @photo.save
post = Datafile.save(upload, @photo.id)
    format.html { redirect_to(@photo, :notice => 'Photo was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @photo, :status => :created, :location => @photo }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
    format.html { redirect_to(@photo, :notice => 'Photo was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @photo.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def destroy
@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
@photo.destroy
respond_to do |format|
post = Datafile.delete(@photo.id)
  format.html { redirect_to(photos_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
end

protected

def authorize
end

end
```

but it wont limit it, can show me what am i missing?

Answer (score 5):

The `authorize` method is not working because you re-defined it as a blank method at the bottom of `PhotosController`. Remove this re-definition and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

swap line from application controller

```
  before_filter :authorize, :except => :login
```

with this

```
helper_method :authorize
```

and paste this line into photos controller

```
before_filter :authorize
```

Comment: `helper_method` makes this method available in the views. This would not fix then problem.